# Incompatible element type Id for collection of Profile

Tags: apex, profile

What am I doing wrong?
I'm trying to find out if a set of profiles' ids contains the user's profile:

```
User u = [select id, ContactId, LanguageLocaleKey, ProfileId from User where id =: Userinfo.getUserId() limit 1];
Set < Profile > profilesSet = new Set < Profile > ([SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE UserType = 'Standard'
    AND((Name LIKE '%regular%') OR(Name LIKE '%Back Office%'))]);
if (profilesSet.contains(u.ProfileId)) {
    dpmUser = true;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a set of `Profile` objects not of `Id` values in your code.

A convenient way to get the set of `Id` values is to use this [Map](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) constructor:

```
Map<Id, Profile> profilesMap = new Map<Id, Profile>([SELECT Id ...]);
if (profilesMap.keySet().contains(u.ProfileId)) {
    dpmUser = true;
}
```

If this is the only check you are doing, you could add a term:

```
AND Id = :u.ProfileId
```

to the `Profile` query and just check if zero or one records are returned.

Also note that there is a [UserInfo.getProfileId()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) method available that would avoid the `User` query if that was the only value you needed.